# Find the derivative of integral $f(x)/(x^2(x-5)^7)$ when $f(x)$ is a quadratic function.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, partial-fractions

This question is quite tricky. It's for my Calculus 2 assignment and I can't seem to figure out how to integrate this function in order to get its derivative. I tried partial fractions, u-sub with x-5 and x^2, but nothing seems to work. All I conluded is that the quadratic function y-coordinate is -4.[image]

Can someone help me with this?

Regards,
You Xiao Ruan.

Comment: The numerator has to be of the form $ax^2+bx-4$ and when you integrate given integral, there cannot be an $ln$. This means that somehow the division has to come out "evenly",i.e. stuff has to cancel out. Now the denominator has two zeros...

Comment: Would a u-sub be helpful here?

Comment: I don't think so. But the zeros of the denominator are very helpful to determine $a$ and $b$. Then stuff is supposed to cancel

Comment: What do you mean by the zeros. I don't think it has to do with improper integrals?

Comment: You want $ax^2+bx-4$ to be divisible by (x-5) for sure. Maybe by $(x-5)^2$....what do you think?

Comment: Actually I perceive a little problem here with the exercise. The thing is that in order not to have an $ln$ as part of an anti derivative, you cannot have a linear term after partial fraction decomposition. I was at first thinking of $f(x)=-4/25(x-5)^2$ because that passes through $(0,-4)$, but after canceling, I checked and it ends up with an $ln$ after integrating. So this can't be it. There has to be some other "non-conventional" trick, which I don't see at the moment. It is getting late here and half my brain is asleep...I did upvote your question.

Comment: See the related question [in here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070180/finding-the-value-of-f0)

Comment: With enough effort, it can be shown that to solve this particular problem for the integral $$\int\dfrac{f(x)}{x^2(x-a)^n}$$ we need $ab-4n=0$.